# Maximum subset of points with certain density

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, np

Suppose a set of points S in a 2D-plane, how to remove the minimum number of points from S such that the distances between any two remaining points is not less than a constant say R.

I guess this could be NP-hard. Can anyone suggest a fast approximate solution? Thanks!

Comment: If there are only 2 points and the distance is less than R, would that result in 0 points?

Comment: @Striker Remove 1 point. You now have one point left and it has no other point closer than R.

Comment: @Striker I think so. There should be empty set left

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It makes sense

Comment: @GilbertLee Just to clarify, are you asking how to do this? or What is the  complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: @Striker I edited my question. thanks

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I edited my question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

My friend suggest a reasonable solution:

Construct a graph G in which all edges are less than R. The set of points to be removed is the same as the minimum vertex cover of the graph G. The approximation of vertex cover is in polynomial time.

Comment: Yep, was just writing this myself.  That approximation is a 2-approximation, which isn't too bad, but Vertex Cover is also fixed parameter tractable in the solution size, so it can be solved exactly on quite large instances, provided only a small number of vertices need to be deleted.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You both genius

Answer (score 0):

This one is fast but not the minimum number of points. Keep in mind the loop should handle changes to set S when removing or disabling a point.

```
 For each Point P1 in S
 {
       For each Point P2 after P1 in S 
       {
             If (square(P1.x - P2.x) + square(P1.y - P2.y) < square(R) )
             {
                   remove (P2)
             }
       }
 }
```

For minimum but expensive:

```
use double loop to store each P2 closest to P1
example: array [P1][P2]

 Sort array based on size of array [P1].numOfElements ()
 such that largest is at the top

 now remove top element P from set S 
 and in  array P1
 and all subsequent P in P2 of all P1

  If P2 is empty for any element X in P1 then remove it

  Remove the next top element and do the process again until array is empty

  Resulting set is the answer for minimum points
```